# Powershell error - GetHostByAddress

Tags: powershell

Stumped on a problem here - running Powershell 1.0

Code (Assume an ip address which is valid is being passed in):

```
$ips = @(Import-CSV $attachmentLocation)
foreach ($ip in $ips){
    $ipAddress = $ip.IPAddress
$length = $ipaddress.length
write-host "Length is: ($length)"
    if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $ipAddress -Count 1 -ea silentlycontinue) {
        write-host $ipAddress
        $hostData = ([Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress($ipAddress)).HostName
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Length is: (11)
10.xx.xx.xx
Exception calling "GetHostByAddress" with "1" argument(s): "The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found"
At FileName:13 char:43
+         $hostData = ([Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress <<<< ($ipAddress)).HostName
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

If I run the following it works fine - seems to be data type issue (im passing in a string value):

```
$hostData = ([Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress("10.xx.xx.xx")).HostName
```

Working Code:

```
$ipAddress = "10.xx.xx.xx"
$hostData = ([Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress($ipAddress)).HostName
```

**Answer:**
Issue was with the ActiveDirectory Domain DNS resolution not the command, while some IP addresses were pingable they were not resolving properly on machine where the script was run. This was causing the error 'no data of the requested type was found' refers to the fact it couldn't resolve the IP to a DNS name.

Comment: Where is $ipaddress coming from?  Any chance there's trailing whitespace? And do you have RDNS on that address?

Comment: No trailing white space, works fine when I type the IP address in directly as a string. Have scoured the internet already with no success. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: What means "issue was with the domain"? Could you explain further?

Comment: @Suncatcher - it was a DNS resolution issue on the ActiveDirectory domain the host was a member of (See the up-marked answer and my comment) ill 'clarify' this in above Answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've got two ideas you could try:

1. `GetHostByAddress()` supports `string` and `ipaddress`. So try casting to `ipaddress`-type before running the function.

   if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $ipAddress -Count 1 -ea silentlycontinue) {
       write-host $ipAddress
       $hostData = ([Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress(([ipaddress]$ipAddress))).HostName
   }
2. If you're on PS 1.0, then your first priority should be to upgrade the machines to at least [PowerShell 2.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929/en-us). Nothing works well in PS 1.0.

Comment: No it doesn't work. There is a good reason I didn't supply the output see my second line of the question below:

"Code (Assume an ip address which is valid is being passed in):"
Therefore no need to send the output as assuming a valid IP address has been entered.

Thanks for your response!

Comment: We need to see how `$ipaddress` is created, we need to see it's value(replace numbers with X if you really have to), and we need to see `$ipaddress.count`. We can't help you when we don't get the necessary info. The sample works perfectly on PS 2.0 ->.

Comment: I've added the 'output' not sure what help its going to give you other then confirming its a string not an object  which I confirmed in the description "(im passing in a string value):". Hope it makes it clearer now.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code. Could you also provide the result of `$ipaddress.count` for the same ip as you've added output for? Also, see my edited answer about PS1.0. :)

Comment: Np - updated above with .count data, just blank as its not an array. See updated code which DOES work at bottom - definitely looks data type related.

Comment: Sry. I meant `Length` :) In powershell 3+, `count` behaves as `length`.

Comment: Hmm. If the same ip works when you specified the ip manually, then I'm blank. I only have to ideas left. See updated answer. EDIT: just saw your edit about working code using a variable. There must be something wrong with your csv-file, but I'm not sure what it is :-/ Could you provide a csv-sample?

Comment: Ok - looks like its a domain problem here, works for some IPs and not others (the DNS is not resolving properly but there pingable). Sorry for wasting your time. Thanks for the answers. +1 for the ideas of casting to IPAddress Type - hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

Running PS3, I get the error shown when traversing subnets on our domain. Especially remote locations.
I'm checking 5 different C-class subnets on our domain to make sure there aren't devices we don't have in AD.
It's also possible some devices aren't PCs with a hostname: routers, switches, firewalls, scanners, and the like.
When my code gets to my local office, no error.

I'm not using a file, instead I generate the subnets via code in the script.